# How can I replace a specific part of a text string in Excel that has a variable location throughout the document?

Tags: excel, text, replace, formula

I have a very simple spreadsheet and I am having trouble coming up with a formula for it.

Each row has a car name, and then 5 images for that car. My naming convention is just to model of the car, with numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 at the end respectively. So for example, row 1 looks like:

Honda Civic | civic1.jpg |  civic2.jpg |  civic3.jpg | civic4.jpg |  civic5.jpg

I am just looking to be able to type in the first image name (civic1.jpg), and have the next 4 cells populate automatically. The thing is I NEED .jpg to be there for all of these. Since car models are all different lengths of text, how can I single out the "." and just replace the character to the left of it with one number higher than the cell to it's left. I've been messing with =LEFT, =RIGHT, =REPLACE, =CONCATENATE, =SEARCH, etc but am not having any luck. I appreciate any help or guidance.

Thanks.

EDIT: I want to add that the number used in the naming convention may not be the only number in the name. I have cars called "A1" and "M2" for example, which will indeed have cells for images named "a11.jpg" and "m22.jpg". Thanks to Tim for bringing this up.

Answer (score 1):

If "Civic1.jpg" is in B2, place the formula below in C2 and fill to the right.

```
=SUBSTITUTE($B2,"1",(COLUMN()-COLUMN($B2)+1))
```

...assuming there's only a single "1" in the value in B2.

Comment: It will not always be the case that the number for the image is not also found in the model name. For instance I have a car called the "A1" so the cell is called "a11.jpg". For this reason I think I need to locate the "." and replace the character to the left of it. It will always be ".jpg" at the end so I was thinking something with finding those 4 characters and replacing the character to the left of them.

Comment: @jwl298, I think you can slightly modify Tim's formula to replace `1.` (with dot) to `(COLUMN()-COLUMN($B2)+1) & "."` like this: `=SUBSTITUTE($B2,"1.",(COLUMN()-COLUMN($B2)+1) & ".")`

Comment: @simoco thanks for the help. I actually went a simpler albeit less elegant route (I just posted the answer)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just making a dedicated row for column numbers 1 - 5, then concatenated the model name, column number, and ".jpg". I created an extra column to type the base model name into (civic) so then the cells to the right just add the column number and .jpg on the end.